# Is there an API to retrieve the country associated with the Google Wallet account

Tags: android, google-play, android-pay

I’m developing an app which will be used to sell products using in-app purchase. The requirement is that, a subset of products should not be available for users in certain countries, say  I’ve 5 products, all 5 should be seen by users in United States but only 3 should be viewed by users in Canada. Additional requirement is that if the Canadian user visits the US, the app should still show the 3 products that is available in Canada. Is there any API/library that I can use for this requirement?

I’m following the In-app billing implementation provided [here](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_integrate.html) for developing the app. I was planning to provide a predefined price (say 999.09) for the items, that shouldn’t be available, as local price in Canada while creating the product in Google Play developer console so that the app can filter out the products from the result of calling IInAppBillingService..getSkuDetails. The problem I’m facing in this implementation is that if the Canadian user is visiting the US the getSkuDetails is retrieving the local price set for the product in US. But, when the user triggers the purchase intent, the price displayed in the pop-up screen is the price set for the product in Canada. I guess the service used by the pop-up screen uses the credit card billing information set in the user’s Google Wallet account and displays the price set in Canada. Is there any API/library which I can use to retrieve the country associated with the Google Wallet account without embedding the Google Wallet Instant Buy button in my app?